# PLINQ iteration of looping enumerator causes deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, plinq

I have a simple program that iterates over an endless enumerable implemented as a feedback enumerator. I have implemented this in both TPL and PLINQ. Both examples lockup after a predictable number of iterations: 8 for PLINQ, and 3 for TPL. It the code is executed without using TPL/PLINQ, it runs fine. I have implemented the enumerator in a non-threadsafe way as well as a threadsafe way. The former can be used if the degree of parallelism is restricted to one (as is the case in the examples). The non-threadsafe enumerator is very simple and does not rely on any 'fancy' .NET library classes. If I increase the degree of parallelism, the number of iterations that are performed before the deadlock increases, e.g for PLINQ the number of iterations is 8 * the degree of parallelism.

Here are the iterators:
**Enumerator (non-threadsafe)**

```
public class SimpleEnumerable<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    private T _value;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _releaseValueEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            _releaseValueEvent.WaitOne();
            yield return _value;
        }
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _releaseValueEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

**Enumerator (threadsafe)**

```
public class SimpleEnumerable<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<T>();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            yield return _blockingCollection.Take();
        }
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        _blockingCollection.Add(value);
    }
}
```

**PLINQ Example:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var enumerable = new SimpleEnumerable<int>();
    enumerable.OnNext(0);

    enumerable
        .Do(i => Debug.WriteLine($"{i} {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"))
        .AsParallel()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)
        .ForEach
        (
            i =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"{i} {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                enumerable.OnNext(i+1);
            }
        );
}
```

**TPL Example:**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var enumerable = new SimpleEnumerable<int>();
    enumerable.OnNext(0);

    Parallel.ForEach
    (
        enumerable,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1},
        i =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{i} {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            enumerable.OnNext(i+1);
        }
    );
}
```

Base on my analysis of the callstack, it appears that there is a deadlock that occurs in a partitioner related method both in PLINQ and TPL, but I am not sure how to interpret this.

Through trial and error I have found the wrapping the PLINQ `enumerable` in `Partitioner.Create(enumerable, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)` fixes the problem, but I am not sure why the deadlock occurs.

I would be very interested in finding out the root cause of the bug.

Note that this is a contrived example. I am not looking for a critique of the code, but rather **why** is the deadlock occurring. Specifically, in the PLINQ example, if the `.AsParallel()` and `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)` lines are commented out, the code works just fine.

Comment: PLINQ and Parallel don't cause deadlocks, they use the current thread together with N others to process data in parallel

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Clearly the deadlock is in his iterator.  At first glance, I'm not surprised, it certainly doesn't look safe at all.

Comment: @Servy I started with the most obvious problem. The iterator ... is a very, very strange construct. A simple 10K array of ints would be more than enough to test parallel execution. `Interlocked.Increment` would be a very nice way to keep count. This iterator, just blocks

Comment: Your code doesn't really *do* anything.  Without knowing what it's *supposed* to do, one couldn't really say how it could be done correctly.

Comment: The only thing this code shows is that an iterator that blocks on a single thread is bad. What is the *actual* problem?

Comment: This is a contrived example distilled from a much more complex piece of code. Perhaps I should have been clearer in what I was asking. I want to know why it is deadlocking. I am not trying to test parallel execution. I have a program that deadlocks and after simplifying the code I have come up with this example. The poignant thing is that the feedback loop that generates the next value causes the deadlock. I want to know why it is deadlocking.

Comment: You may say that PLINQ does not cause deadlocks, but if I break the above program while it is executing, the threads are waiting in the PLINQ partitioner. The deadlock is not in the enumerator.

Comment: @TomasC Buffering enumerates results with mm.. buffering, first several results are processed just as they are received, after 4 results it starts enumerate in batches (4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128) and buffer results before paralleling. You receive deadlock when buffering starts, as in this moment you have two WaitOne in a row with single Set.. and that's it. As you disable buffering, everything is fine, because you have result processing after each GetNext in enumerator.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually have a logical sequence of values, so trying to create an `IEnumerable` in the first place simply doesn't make any sense.  Additionally, you should almost certainly not be trying to create an `IEnumerator` that can be consumed by multiple threads.  There lies madness, simply because the interface that `IEnumerator` exposes isn't really exposing what you'd want it to in order to do that.  You can potentially create an `IEnumerator` that will only ever be used by a single thread that compute the data to return based on an underlying data source that is used by multiple threads though, as that's rather different.

If you simply want to create a producer and a consumer that run in different threads, don't create your own "wrapper" around `BlockingCollection`, *just use `BlockingCollection`.  Have the producer add to it, and the consumer read from it.  The consumer can use `GetConsumingEnumerable` if it just wants to iterate over items while taking those items (a common operation to want to do).

Comment: The example that I gave is distilled from entirely different code. It is a contrived example to demonstrate the problem. The original code did not use and enumerator, or a blocking collection. I appreciate your comments, but I would say you have missed the point of the exercise entirely. I was not so much asking for a critique of 'what' the code is doing or 'how' the code is doing it, but rather 'why' is the code deadlocking in PLINQ & TPL.

Comment: @TomasC You saying that the code you actually care about looks nothing at all like the code that you showed means that you couldn't possibly get any information about what you care about then.  If you ask a question about how to use an iterator from multiple threads when you don't actually have an enumerator and it shares none of the implementation details of your example, then we know literally nothing about you situation, and obviously couldn't comment on it.  We can only ever comment on the code you actually provide.

Comment: I am quite aware of how to use an enumerator. I did not ask about how to use an enumerator from multiple threads. I know how to do that. I simply have some behaviour in PLINQ code that is causing a deadlock and I was hoping to get a reason as to why it was deadlocking (as I clearly stated in my previous comment). You seem to be ignoring the question I am asking, i.e. why is it deadlocking? That's all I want to know. Otherwise, your comments are much appreciated and very insightful.

Comment: @TomasC The code is structured in an entirely nonsensical way and is unquestionably not even close to being the right tools to solve any problem.  A deadlock you're encountering in an approach that you shouldn't use, and apparently *aren't* using, isn't meaningful to anyone.  If you use the appropriate tools your code wouldn't deadlock.  If your entirely different solution that this apparently isn't a representative example of is deadlocking, then it has nothing to do with this code, and whatever deadlocks it might have (by your own admission).